# PINAX, django-user-accounts and signup code

Tags: python, django, web, pinax

I am trying to use Pinax with the included django-user-accounts app. I cannot find how I can generate a "signup code" and send it to the user, after the former fills up a form. Is it supported by django-user-accounts or do I have to do it by myself?

Comment: Do you want an email confirmation after the signup process or what?

Comment: I need to send a "signup code" first and, with that signup code, users can start registering within the system. I would like to do it this way since the administrator of the website can control to whom to send the "signup code" - kind of an invitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signup-code part of `django-user-accounts` originally comes from the [`pinax.apps.signup_codes`](https://gitorious.org/pinax/pinax/source/7c09913e46d3c44c4693271a4b6c6b4cb4f01acb%3apinax/apps/signup_codes) project.

And it seems like they missed to include the [`admin_invite_user`](https://gitorious.org/pinax/pinax/source/7c09913e46d3c44c4693271a4b6c6b4cb4f01acb%3apinax/apps/signup_codes/views.py#L100) view and the [`InviteUserForm`](https://gitorious.org/pinax/pinax/source/7c09913e46d3c44c4693271a4b6c6b4cb4f01acb%3apinax/apps/signup_codes/forms.py#L31) too.

So the solution is :

- right you own views (inspired by [the original ones](https://gitorious.org/pinax/pinax/source/7c09913e46d3c44c4693271a4b6c6b4cb4f01acb%3apinax/apps/signup_codes/views.py#L100))
- or use [my pull request](https://github.com/pinax/django-user-accounts/issues/98) on github

Comment: In the end, I slightly changed the "sign up" process, so that I now show the "user request for registration" to a system administration and, afterwards, the administrator is the one who has the responsibility for accepting the users. In case the registration request is accepted, the system returns to the usual registration process through the email confirmation code.

Comment: This workflow is interesting when it comes to add an "extra" verification of the user identity. I have almost ready the administrator interface that will permit this additional identity verification.